# How can I add a keybinding to open the active file in the Explorer and move focus to the editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

I'd like to change the 'o' keybinding when in the file explorer of VS Code.

For a directory I'd like to keep the expand/collapse behavior, but for files I'd like the file to open (current behavior) and for the cursor to move to the editor.

Comment: what command is bound to `o`, according to the key bind GUI there is no command bound to `o`

Comment: "_For a directory I'd like to keep the expand/collapse behavior_" - `o` does not do this. Are you saying you'd like an answer to show _how_ to make `o` do this as well?

Comment: loosely related: [How can I set focus to the editor after clicking a file in the Explorer View?](/q/75951425/11107541)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the following (open keybingings.json with `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` in the command palette):

```json
{
    // open file and pass focus to editor
    "key": "o",
    "when": "filesExplorerFocus && !explorerResourceIsFolder",
    "command": "explorer.openAndPassFocus"
},
{
    // toggle folder folding
    "key": "o",
    "when": "filesExplorerFocus && explorerResourceIsFolder",
    "command": "list.select"
}
```

If you still want to be able to type file names to do quick searches in the Explorer, try adding the following to the when-clauses `&& !inputFocus && !textInputFocus && !inInteractiveInput && !renameInputVisible`.